# Copy txt file from Azure Files to Blob Storage using Databricks

Tags: python-3.x, azure-blob-storage, databricks, dbutils, storage-file-share

I want to read a file from Azure Files (which is succeeded by using ShareClient) and export this file to Azure blob storage.

First I mount the container in Databricks with the following code:

```
def mount(container, account_name):
    """Mount a container in blob storage"""
    mount_list = [_.mountPoint for _ in dbutils.fs.mounts()]
    mount_point = f"/mnt/{container}/"
    if mount_point not in mount_list:
        dbutils.fs.mount(
                source = f"wasbs://{container}@{account_name}.blob.core.windows.net/",
                mount_point = mount_point,
                extra_configs = {f"fs.azure.account.key.saweaaedwh.blob.core.windows.net":dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "KEY-WE-AAE-DWH", key = f"key-{account_name}")})
        print(f"Container {container} is successfully mounted")
    else:
        print("Container is already mounted")
```

When I want to upload a file with following code:

```
with open(f"/dbfs/mnt/datascience/spc/failed2/test.txt", "wb") as outfile:
    download_stream = file_client.download_file()
    outfile.write(download_stream.readall())
```

The following error message comes in:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dbfs/mnt/datascience/spc/failed2/test.txt'
```

In order to create this directory I used this code:

```
dbutils.fs.mkdirs('/mnt/datascience/spc/failed2/test.txt')
```

The problem is that this also create 'empty' directories. Do you know how to create only directories if it contains at least 1 file??

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Vpu5.png)

Comment: COuld you please describe your issue indetail? The path `/dbfs/mnt/datascience/spc/failed2` does not exist and you want to create a file in the path . Right?

Comment: I mounted Blob storage with Databricks with the first code snippet. After that I want to upload a txt file to the blob storage. Where the directory spc/failed2 does not exist yet. So I use dbutils.fs.mkdirs to create such a directory. Then there are empty folders and normal folders created (duplicates), which looks like a mess. (See the image what is created)

Comment: The Azure Blob service is based on a flat storage scheme, not a hierarchical scheme. It  does not have `directory`. It just uses a character or string delimiter within a blob name to create a virtual hierarchy. So when we use dbutils.fs.mkdirs to create things, the Blob server just considers that we want to create blobs. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/naming-and-referencing-containers--blobs--and-metadata#blob-names.